# WCF Protocol Error. What have I missed?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have constructed a WCF service that works fine with the standard settings but then I decided to try and implement a SOAP 1.2 binding. Since making the changes to the web.config and the client code I now find that I am getting a protocol exception and I have no idea why or what causes it. Please see my code below. The configuration looks correct to me so I can only guess there is a problem in the client code. Any ideas more than welcome:

**The web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Namespace.ServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="EToNServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="EToNSoap12" address=""
                  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="soap12"
                  bindingNamespace="http://www.wrcplc.co.uk/Schemas/ETON"
                  contract="Namespace.IInterfaceName" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EToNServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="soap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**The Interface**

```
namespace TheNamespace
{
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

/// <summary>
/// An interface to describe the contract offered by a class of this type.
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInterfaceName
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// A method to receive an EtoN notice
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The EtoN message</param>
    [OperationContract (Name = "StoreNotice")]
    [WebInvoke (Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "StoreNotice")]
    Message StoreNotice (Message message);
    }
}
```

**The Client Code**

```
public string CallPostMethod()
    {
        const string action = "StoreNotice";

        TestNotice testNotice = new TestNotice();

        const string url = "http://myIp:myPort/ServiceName.svc/StoreNotice";

        string contentType = String.Format("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=\"{0}\"", action);
        string xmlString = CreateSoapMessage(url, action, testNotice.NoticeText);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] bytesToSend = encoding.GetBytes(xmlString);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = bytesToSend.Length;
        request.ContentType = contentType;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        string responseFromServer;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(responseFromServer); 

            return document.ToString();
        }
        catch(WebException e)
            {
            throw e;
            }
    }

    protected string CreateSoapMessage(string url, string action, string messageContent)
    {
        return String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""    xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
            <soap12:Body>
            {0}
            </soap12:Body>
        </soap12:Envelope>", messageContent, action, url);
    }
```

**EDIT**

By using the trace viewer I have been presented with this information:

> The message with To
>   'http://localhost:56919/TmaNoticeToClusteredEntityWcfService.svc/StoreNotice'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.

What is wrong with my code that would produce this? It looks ok to me.

Comment: And the exact exception is ...

Comment: It does not tell me. Inner exception is null. Status is System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError and the message is the ever useful: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: The it's time to set up diagnostics in the server.

Comment: I am running on localhost using either IIS express or the ASP.NET development server. How do I enable diagnostics on these?

Comment: Attach the debugger. Or simply start the server form another copy of VS.

Comment: I am running the service in debug mode but there is just no further information coming forward with the exception. The code breaks on the line     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If client is a .Net application you can create service proxy to call it as below.

```
Proxy.ServiceClient client = new Proxy.ServiceClient();
client.StoreNotice(GetMessage());
```

Method GetMessage()

```
 public static Message GetMessage()
        {
            //create an XML reader from the input XML
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CreateSoapMessage("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFCustomEndpointService/Service1/", "http://tempuri.org/IService1/StoreNotice", "content"))));

            //create a WCF message from the XML reader
            Message inputMessge = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/StoreNotice", reader);

            return inputMessge;
        }
```

Copy of your method CreateSoapMessage

```
 protected static string CreateSoapMessage(string url, string action, string messageContent)
        {
            return String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope""><soap12:Body>{0}</soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>", messageContent, action, url);
        }
```

Comment: For some reason this code does not populate the XmlReader object.

Comment: have you replaced the visual studio design time URLs ?  - http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ and http://tempuri.org/IService1/StoreNotice

Comment: Thanks I got it working in the end. It wasnt exactly what I wanted but it works so satisfies my requirements.